# how to find route of two place

Tags: algorithm

i have 3 buses with 3 routes lets name our buses with bus-A,bus-B,bus-C and their routes with r1,r2,r3.. so, the places that are included in their routes are

```
bus-A route is r1
bus-B route is r2
bus-C route is r3

r1:[badoc,pin,curri,bat,san,laoag](vise versa)
r2:[pag,bang,bur,pas,bac,laoag](vise versa)
r3:[ban,mar,ding,san,laoag](vise versa)
```

and i want to find the closest route for

```
CURRENT LOCATION:badoc
TARGET LOCATION:laoag
```

please help me how the algorithm should get the route... thanks alot!

Comment: 'bad' is not even in one of the routes....

Comment: OH SORRY THAT SHOULD BE "badoc"

Comment: so edit your question, please

Answer (score 1):

Your Problem can be solved using [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). Think of the bus stops as nodes and use weight one for each of the edges.

Comment: thanks nick... i will probably try that... i will implement that algo in php ... what do you think are they compatible?

Comment: Since it is an algorithm, i.e. an abstract set of instructions, it is surely compatible with PHP as with any other language

Comment: http://en.giswiki.net/wiki/Algorithmus_von_Dijkstra#PHP this might help you... the page is in german but the code comments and everything are english ;)

Comment: Dijkstra is an overkill here since the problem is not weighted. BFS will be faster and easier to code. Look at my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Since the graph modeling this problem is not weighted, there is no need for Dijkstra's Algorithm in here.

[BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) will also find the shortest path - and is both easier to code and will find the solution faster.

Module your graph as `G=(V,E)` such that `V = { all stops }` and `E = {(v,u) | u follows v as a stop in some bus }`

After creating the graph, just run a BFS - the solution found by BFS is [guaranteed to be optimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Optimality).

Comment: @NjLac: Sorry, I know nothing about php [hopefully I will fix it in the next summer]. But BFS is very simple, it can be written with at most a few dozens lines. [in some languages even less then a dozen]. Try to read the wikipedia page and understand how it works. If you do not understand something about it - you can always post a question about it!